# how to use Stripe in laravel without using composer?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

my project has been done with laravel 7 and its on a real host with cpanel as server software.

I want to online payment to website and I think Stripe is the best option but I cant figure it out how to use it without composer.

in every tutorial people used composer commands for doing this automatically, but in my case I have to put files one by one and update files.

I asked host provider about giving me composer ability on apache, but they said they cant so I have to do every thing manually.

I would be very glad if you could help me in this.

Comment: Each Laravel project uses composer, without it autoloading, namespacing won't be possible and basically, Laravel won't work!

Comment: The best solution is, download your project from your server. Add `.git` for tracking. delete `.gitignore` file from root.  Now install your stripe from `composer`. When you finish your work, you can check `git status` to check which files has changed and added. Add those on your live server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the Composer in your Hosting-Environment, If you have it in your Local-Environment then you will have the files already installed on your server. You could try [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead) what is already a pre-configured local-development environment for Laravel.

[Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) is only a dependency-management-system, what makes you really easier to use open-source-code from other third party providers like the STRIPE-SDK.

But you can also use Stripes RAW REST-API's without the SDK, but it would be much more work - you can for example extract the needed parameters from the [curl-example of stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=curl), but also if you use this direct way It would be easier to use a Curl-Wrapper-Library like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/).

You should really have a deeper look into the composer, because if you want to use & contribute with some community-projects you need composer.

---

BTW: when you install laravel from scratch, then you still use the composer, as you see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation).

Comment: Thanks for the curl-example link!  Oddly I couldn't find any links in the docs to the CURL examples.  Even though it's the default, there doesn't seem to be a way in the UI to reset to it.  Adding ?lang=curl to the url or deleting/modifying the lang cookie both work.

Answer (score 1):

While Composer is the recommended option, Stripe supports manual installation by downloading a specific version of their library and including it directly. It's also covered directly on their readme page here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#manual-installation

You install the library locally by downloading the latest release and unzipping it, you add this to your own code and then you include the library like this:

```
require_once('/path/to/stripe-php/init.php');
```